# R : catching errors in `nls`

Tags: r, exception, curve-fitting, nls

I'm fitting some exponential data using `nls`.

The code I'm using is:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ expFit(times, A, tau, C), start = c(A=100, tau=-3, C=0))
```

`expFit` is defined as

```
expFit <- function(t, A, tau, C)
    {
    expFit <- A*(exp(-t/tau))+C
    }
```

This works well for most of my data, for which the starting parameters provided (100, -3 and 0) work well. Sometimes, though, I have data that doesn't go well with those parameters and I get errors from `nls` (e.g. "singular gradient" or things like that). How do I "catch" these errors?

I tried to do something like

```
fit <- NULL
fit <- nls(...)

if (is.null(fit))
    {
    // Try nls with other starting parameters
    }
```

But this won't work because `nls` seems to stop the execution and the code after `nls` will not execute...

Any ideas?

Thanks
nico

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually use this trick:

```
params<-... # setup default params.

while(TRUE){

fit<-NULL
try(fit<-nls(...)); # does not stop in the case of error

if(!is.null(fit))break; # if nls works, then quit from the loop

params<-... # change the params for nls

}
```

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I needed!

I just added a `silent="TRUE"` parameter to try, so I don't get errors printed out.

Comment: @kohske The logic of your answer makes sense. It is useful to know about the `try` command but I was expecting a nls call on line four of your post and am unfamiliar with the nul function that appears there. A quick search here hasn't helped me find out what nul does. Have you any hints on where to find out more on this? Maybe I don't know which package I should require?

Comment: @JasonWhyte That's just a typo. I meant `try(fit <- nls(...))` and fit will be NULL when `nls` induces an error.

Comment: @kohske Thanks for the clarification. I was clutching at straws because using the solution above with nls (instead of nul) still didn't help me in all cases as the nls fitting seemed stuck in a loop. I've since worked out that I'm dealing with a completely different type of nls bug, one that doesn't return an error. I'll document this soon.